# count work order history for each location with filters

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I have a work orders history table that has the following columns. I need to count the number of **Need Spares** (wo_status=2) work orders that have been **Closed** (wo_status=4) for each location between a particular date span.

| work_order_num | equipment_name | location | wo_status | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55261 | Endoscopy | 15 | 5 | 2022-11-02 09:39:05 |
| 55261 | Endoscopy | 15 | 3 | 2022-11-02 09:39:05 |
| 55261 | Endoscopy | 15 | 4 | 2022-11-02 09:39:05 |
| 55262 | Endoscopy | 15 | 5 | 2022-11-02 09:39:05 |
| 55262 | Endoscopy | 15 | 3 | 2022-11-02 09:39:05 |
| 55262 | Endoscopy | 15 | 2 | 2022-11-02 09:39:05 |
| 55262 | Endoscopy | 15 | 2 | 2022-11-02 09:39:05 |
| 55262 | Endoscopy | 15 | 4 | 2022-11-02 09:39:05 |
| 55263 | Baby Warmer | 37 | 5 | 2022-11-08 09:39:05 |
| 55263 | Baby Warmer | 37 | 3 | 2022-11-08 09:39:05 |
| 55263 | Baby Warmer | 37 | 4 | 2022-11-08 09:39:05 |
| 55264 | Baby Warmer | 37 | 5 | 2022-11-08 09:39:05 |
| 55264 | Baby Warmer | 37 | 3 | 2022-11-08 09:39:05 |
| 55264 | Baby Warmer | 37 | 2 | 2022-11-08 09:39:05 |
| 55264 | Baby Warmer | 37 | 2 | 2022-11-08 09:39:05 |
| 55264 | Baby Warmer | 37 | 4 | 2022-11-08 09:39:05 |

**More Details**

Work order number 55261 and 55263 should not be considered as they have been **Closed** without going into **Need Spares** status.

Work order number 55262 and 55264 have two rows of wo_status=2 so, it should count only 1 row in each work order. For some reason, there are work orders in my table that have multiple rows with the same work order status.

What I have done so far is

```
SELECT d.name district_name, 
sum(case when w.`wo_status`='2' then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS need_spares, 
sum(case when w.`wo_status`='4' then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS closed 
FROM `work_orders_history` w
LEFT JOIN berc_locations l ON w.location=l.ID
LEFT JOIN berc_cities c ON l.city_id=c.ID
LEFT JOIN berc_districts d ON c.district_id=d.ID
WHERE (w.`created_at` BETWEEN '2022-09-19 00:00:00' AND '2022-11-30 00:00:00')
AND w.`wo_status` IN(2,4)
GROUP BY d.`name`
ORDER BY closed DESC
```

The above query is returning me data in the format like this

| district_name | need_spares | closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mianwali | 4 | 15 |
| Sargodha | 17 | 22 |
| Rawalpindi | 19 | 82 |
| Lahore | 17 | 29 |

The query is considering work orders like 55261 and 55263 due to which **closed** count is exceeding from the total number of need **spares**, and also it is counting all multiple rows (where wo_status=2) instead of treating them as 1 entity. Can someone please help me in fixing this query. Thanks in advance

**EDITS**

My Expected output

| district_name | need_spares | closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mianwali | 4 | 3 |
| Sargodha | 17 | 17 |
| Rawalpindi | 19 | 12 |
| Lahore | 14 | 9 |

The number of **Closed** work orders should not exceed the **Need Spares** work orders count if the above-mentioned conditions are considered correctly.

Comment: please include the table schema

Comment: Can you share the expected output table?

Comment: Are you using MySQL v5.7?

Comment: Yes 5.7.21 to be exact